# Filtering (reducing) a NumPy Array

Tags: python, numpy, cython, numba

Suppose I have a NumPy array `arr` that I want to element-wise filter (reduce) depending on the truth value of a (broadcastable) function, e.g.
I want to get only values below a certain threshold value `k`:

```py
def cond(x):
    return x < k
```

There are a couple of methods, e.g.:

1. Using a generator: `np.fromiter((x for x in arr if cond(x)), dtype=arr.dtype)` (which is a memory efficient version of using a list comprehension: `np.array([x for x in arr if cond(x)])` because [`np.fromiter()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) will produce a NumPy array directly, without the need to allocate an intermediate Python `list`)
2. Using boolean masking: `arr[cond(arr)]`
3. Using integer indexing: `arr[np.nonzero(cond(arr))]` (or equivalently using [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) as it defaults to [`np.nonzero()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) with only one condition)
4. Using explicit looping with:

   - single pass and final copying/resizing
   - two passes: one to determine the size of the result and one to actually perform the computation

(The last two approaches to be accelerated with [Cython](https://cython.org/) or [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/))

Which is the fastest? What about memory efficiency?

---

(EDITED: To use directly `np.nonzero()` instead of `np.where()` as per  @ShadowRanger comment)

Comment: Option #1 is completely different from options 2 & 3. It returns a new array of booleans (cast to the original `dtype`), not a new filtered array.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for spotting that, fixed now.

Comment: K. One additional note: `numpy`'s own docs discourage using `numpy.where` with just a condition. `numpy.where(condition)` (only a condition, no `x`/`y` args) is equivalent to `numpy.asarray(condition).nonzero()`; the recommended approach is to call `.nonzero()` directly, e.g. `arr[(arr < k).nonzero()]`. Handles subclasses correctly, and runs a little faster that way to boot.

Comment: @ShadowRanger do you have any idea what the difference between `arr[(arr > k).nonzero()]` and `arr[arr > k]` would be? They perform identically on some simple tests.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I have included it in the tests and the short answer is "not so much".

Answer (score 113, accepted):

## Summary

Using a loop-based approach with single pass and copying, accelerated with Numba, offers the best overall trade-off in terms of speed, memory efficiency and flexibility.
If the execution of the condition function is sufficiently fast, two-passes (`filter2_nb()`) may be faster, while they are more memory efficient regardless.
Also, for sufficiently large inputs, resizing instead of copying (`filter_resize_xnb()`) leads to faster execution.

If the data type (and the condition function) is known ahead of time and can be compiled, the Cython acceleration seems to be faster.
It is likely that a similar hard-coding of the condition would lead to comparable speed-up with Numba accerelation as well.

When it comes to NumPy-only based approaches, boolean masking or integer indexing are of comparable speed, and which one comes out faster depends largely on the filtering factor, i.e. the portion of values that passes through the filtering condition.

The `np.fromiter()` approach is **much** slower (it would be off-charts in the plot), but does not produce large temporary objects.

Note that the following tests are meant to give some insights into the different approaches and should be taken with a grain of salt.
The most relevant assumptions are that the condition is broadcastable and that it would eventually compute very fast.

---

## Definitions

1. Using a generator:

```py
def filter_fromiter(arr, cond):
    return np.fromiter((x for x in arr if cond(x)), dtype=arr.dtype)
```

2. Using boolean masking:

```py
def filter_mask(arr, cond):
    return arr[cond(arr)]
```

3. Using integer indexing:

```py
def filter_idx(arr, cond):
    return arr[np.nonzero(cond(arr))]
```

4a. Using explicit looping, with single pass and final copying/resizing

- Cython-accelerated with copying (pre-compiled condition)

```
%%cython -c-O3 -c-march=native -a
#cython: language_level=3, boundscheck=False, wraparound=False, initializedcheck=False, cdivision=True, infer_types=True


import numpy as np


cdef long NUM = 1048576
cdef long MAX_VAL = 1048576
cdef long K = 1048576 // 2


cdef int cond_cy(long x, long k=K):
    return x < k


cdef size_t _filter_cy(long[:] arr, long[:] result, size_t size):
    cdef size_t j = 0
    for i in range(size):
        if cond_cy(arr[i]):
            result[j] = arr[i]
            j += 1
    return j


def filter_cy(arr):
    result = np.empty_like(arr)
    new_size = _filter_cy(arr, result, arr.size)
    return result[:new_size].copy()
```

- Cython-accelerated with resizing (pre-compiled condition)

```
def filter_resize_cy(arr):
    result = np.empty_like(arr)
    new_size = _filter_cy(arr, result, arr.size)
    result.resize(new_size)
    return result
```

- Numba-accelerated with copying

```py
import numba as nb


@nb.njit
def cond_nb(x, k=K):
    return x < k


@nb.njit
def filter_nb(arr, cond_nb):
    result = np.empty_like(arr)
    j = 0
    for i in range(arr.size):
        if cond_nb(arr[i]):
            result[j] = arr[i]
            j += 1
    return result[:j].copy()
```

- Numba-accelerated with resizing

```py
@nb.njit
def _filter_out_nb(arr, out, cond_nb):
    j = 0
    for i in range(arr.size):
        if cond_nb(arr[i]):
            out[j] = arr[i]
            j += 1
    return j


def filter_resize_xnb(arr, cond_nb):
    result = np.empty_like(arr)
    j = _filter_out_nb(arr, result, cond_nb)
    result.resize(j, refcheck=False)  # unsupported in NoPython mode
    return result
```

- Numba-accelerated with a generator and `np.fromiter()`

```py
@nb.njit
def filter_gen_nb(arr, cond_nb):
    for i in range(arr.size):
        if cond_nb(arr[i]):
            yield arr[i]


def filter_gen_xnb(arr, cond_nb):
    return np.fromiter(filter_gen_nb(arr, cond_nb), dtype=arr.dtype)
```

4b. Using explicit looping with two passes: one to determine the size of the result and one to actually perform the computation

- Cython-accelerated (pre-compiled condition)

```
%%cython -c-O3 -c-march=native -a
#cython: language_level=3, boundscheck=False, wraparound=False, initializedcheck=False, cdivision=True, infer_types=True


cdef size_t _filtered_size_cy(long[:] arr, size_t size):
    cdef size_t j = 0
    for i in range(size):
        if cond_cy(arr[i]):
            j += 1
    return j


def filter2_cy(arr):
    cdef size_t new_size = _filtered_size_cy(arr, arr.size)
    result = np.empty(new_size, dtype=arr.dtype)
    new_size = _filter_cy(arr, result, arr.size)
    return result
```

- Numba-accelerated

```py
@nb.njit
def filter2_nb(arr, cond_nb):
    j = 0
    for i in range(arr.size):
        if cond_nb(arr[i]):
            j += 1
    result = np.empty(j, dtype=arr.dtype)
    j = 0
    for i in range(arr.size):
        if cond_nb(arr[i]):
            result[j] = arr[i]
            j += 1
    return result
```

---

## Timing Benchmarks

(The generator-based `filter_fromiter()` method is much slower than the others -- by approx. 2 orders of magnitude.
Similar (and perhaps slightly worse) performances can be expected from a list comprehension.
This would be true for any explicit looping with non-accelerated code.)

The timing would depend on both the input array size and the percent of filtered items.

### As a function of input size

The first graph addresses the timings as a function of the input size (for ~50% filtering factor -- i.e. 50% of the elements appear in the result):

[image: bm_size]

In general, explicit looping with one form of acceleration leads to the fastest execution, with slight variations depending on input size.

Within NumPy, the integer indexing approaches are basically on par with boolean masking.

The benefits of using `np.fromiter()` (no pre-allocation) can be reaped by writing a Numba-accelerated generator, which would come out slower than the other approaches (within an order of magnitude), but much faster than pure-Python looping.

### As a function of filling

The second graph addresses the timings as a function of items passing through the filter (for a fixed input size of ~1 million elements):

[image: bm_filling]

The first observation is that all methods are slowest when approaching a ~50% filling and with less, or more filling they are faster, and fastest towards no filling (highest percent of filtered-out values, lowest percent of passing through values as indicated in the x-axis of the graph).

Again, explicit looping with some mean of acceleration leads to the fastest execution.

Within NumPy, the integer indexing and boolean masking approaches are again basically the same.

(Full code available [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SkZhw7wJrPTPWEJbhi1NWQZpScoG8918))

---

## Memory Considerations

The generator-based `filter_fromiter()` method requires only minimal temporary storage, independently of the size of the input.
Memory-wise this is the most efficient method.
This approach can be effectively speed up with a Numba-accelerated generator.

Of similar memory efficiency are the Cython / Numba two-passes methods, because the size of the output is determined during the first pass.
The caveat here is that computing the condition has to be fast for these methods to be fast.

On the memory side, the single-pass solutions for both Cython and Numba require a temporary array of the size of the input.
Hence, these are not very memory-efficient compared to two-passes or the generator-based one.

Yet they are of similar asymptotic temporary memory footprint compared to masking, but the constant term is typically larger than masking.

The boolean masking solution requires a temporary array of the size of the input but of type `bool`, which in NumPy is 1 byte, so this is ~8 times smaller than the default size of a NumPy array on a typical 64-bit system.

The integer indexing solution has the same requirement as the boolean mask slicing in the first step (inside `np.nonzero()` call), which gets converted to a series of `int`s (typically `int64` on a 64-bit system) in the second step (the output of `np.nonzero()`).
This second step, therefore, has variable memory requirements, depending on the number of filtered elements.

---

## Remarks

- both boolean masking and integer indexing require some form of conditioning that is capable of producing a boolean mask (or, alternatively, a list of indices); in the above implementation, the condition is broadcastable
- the generator and the Numba-accelerated methods are also the most flexible when it comes to specifying a different filtering condition
- the Numba-accelerated methods require the condition to be Numba-compatible to access the Numba acceleration in NoPython mode
- the Cython solution requires specifying the data types for it to be fast, or extra effort for multiple types dispatching, and extra effort (not explored here) to get the same level of flexibility as the other methods
- for both Numba and Cython, the filtering condition can be hard-coded, leading to marginal but appreaciable speed differences
- the single-pass solutions require additional code to handle the unused (but otherwise initially allotted) memory.
- the NumPy methods do *NOT* return a view of the input, but a copy, as a result of [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```py
arr = np.arange(100)
k = 50
print('`arr[arr > k]` is a copy: ', arr[arr > k].base is None)
# `arr[arr > k]` is a copy:  True
print('`arr[np.where(arr > k)]` is a copy: ', arr[np.where(arr > k)].base is None)
# `arr[np.where(arr > k)]` is a copy:  True
print('`arr[:k]` is a copy: ', arr[:k].base is None)
# `arr[:k]` is a copy:  False
```

---

(EDITED: various improvements based on @ShadowRanger, @PaulPanzer, @max9111 and @DavidW comments.)

Comment: Nice effort---I have long suspected that passing a mask through `where` is typically faster (though it shouldn't be), so thanks for confirming that. I don't think, though, that the Cython and numba implementations are fair. Both basically leak the over allocated memory, something a proper library function isn't allowed to do.

Comment: The differences between cython and numba for medium-sizes are probably due to gcc vs clang, gcc seems to have problems to get best out of such filtering functions (see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/52046301/5769463). For larger sizes, i.e. other cache-levels, the task becomes more and more memory-bound and thus there are less differences between cython and numba.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I have added an extra call to `.copy()` before returning the results. This should make sure no memory leaks.

Comment: It would be almost in every case faster to run the for loop twice. (Fist run to get the final array size, Second run to copy the data which fulfills the condition to the output array allocated with the final size from the first run)

Comment: As the code gets a bit longer, it maybe also useful to write a function which generates the custom filter based on a given condition (>,<,==,..) instead of hard-coding the condition. eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58418715/4045774 Small functions are getting inlined, so there shouldn't be any decrease in performance.

Comment: @max9111 thanks for your inputs, your comments hint towards useful modification. I am running the new benchmarks and will update the answer accordingly. Passing functions instead of hardcoding the condition does decrease the performances, but it is only noticeable for the smallest input sizes. The two-passes approach goes from slower to faster than single-pass as the input size increases.

Comment: Don't use global variables, default values like `smaller_than(x, k=K)` or passing the condition on every call (generate the function only once). This will lead to recompilation on every call and therefore to decreased performance especially on small input sizes.

Comment: Was hoping for a TL;DR somewhere.

Comment: The `fromiter` way does not work for object arrays.

Comment: @Xxxo Sure, but that is somewhat a limitation of [numpy.fromiter](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) itself.

Comment: Would `ndarray.resize` not work to release the extra memory for the single pass versions without needing to copy?

Comment: @DavidW in Cython yes, in Numba not right away. However, one can lift only the filtering loop to Numba and get faster timing (but larger temporary memory consumption) with single pass for sufficiently large inputs.

Comment: Why is `np.nonzero()`-based approach faster than boolean mask slicing for large input?

Comment: @xskxzr why do you say so? My benchmarks indicate them to be of comparable speed.

Comment: Using numba `njit` can make NumPy indexing functions **~2x** faster comparing without it.