# Filtering in numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Want to filter `numpy array` based on a condition with using only numpy

```
sample = ["aple","mangp", "orange"]
np.where("p" in sample)

Op:

(array([], dtype=int64),)

Expected OP:

(array([1,1,0], dtype=int64),)
```

Pointers on my mistake would be great

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58422690/filtering-a-numpy-array-what-is-the-best-approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sample = ["aple", "mangp", "orange"]
np.where(["p" in s for s in sample])
```

> (array([0, 1]),)

which corresponds to the indexes of the true elements.

Your expected output is just given by:

```
np.array(["p" in s for s in sample]).astype(int)
```