# Remove specific elements from a np array based on a expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

How do you filter out elements from a np array by using a expression?
Say I had array `arr = np.array(range(16))` then I want to filter out all numbers that are not perfectly divisible by 5 or 3, how would I do that? can you use `np.remove()` to do this?
if so how?
Thanks!

Comment: There is a `np.delete`, but you specify the removals by index, not by some sort of value.  But with any removal, what you are really doing is selecting the elements you want to copy to a new array.

Comment: take a look at [Filtering a NumPy Array: what is the best approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58422690/14750360)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering a NumPy Array: what is the best approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58422690/filtering-a-numpy-array-what-is-the-best-approach)

Comment: A good general approach is to construct a boolean mask, the size of the original array, which is True for the values you want to keep, and False for the removal ones.  Then `res = arr[mask]`.